# count similar values from list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries and I need to count unique entries.
Then I need to sort the values based on the tuple that is part of the key "corrected_word" (2 < 3 < 33)

```
mylist = [
{'original_word': 'test1', 'corrected_word': ('test12', 3)},
{'original_word': 'test1', 'corrected_word': ('test12', 3)},
{'original_word': 'test2', 'corrected_word': ('test22', 2)},
{'original_word': 'test3', 'corrected_word': ('test3', 33)},
{'original_word': 'test3', 'corrected_word': ('test3', 33)},
{'original_word': 'test3', 'corrected_word': ('test3', 33)}
]
```

Expected Output:

```
mylist = [
{'original_word': 'test2', 'corrected_word': ('test22', 2, 1)},
{'original_word': 'test1', 'corrected_word': ('test12', 3, 2)},
{'original_word': 'test3', 'corrected_word': ('test3', 33, 3)}
]
```

I have tried this:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter([str(i) for i in mylist])
```

But it does not return the list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of tuples, where the first element of each tuple is the original word, and the remaining elements are the elements in the corresponding `corrected_word`  tuple. Then put this list through `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
ctr = Counter(((item['original_word'], *item['corrected_word']) for item in mylist))
```

This gives:

```
Counter({('test3', 'test3', 33): 3, ('test1', 'test12', 3): 2, ('test2', 'test22', 2): 1})
```

Then, build your result list and sort it by the value you want:

```
result = sorted([
          {'original_word': ow, 'corrected_word': (*cw, count)} for (ow, *cw), count in ctr.items()
          ], key=lambda item: item['corrected_word'][1])
```

Which gives the desired result:

```
[
 {'original_word': 'test2', 'corrected_word': ('test22', 2, 1)},
 {'original_word': 'test1', 'corrected_word': ('test12', 3, 2)},
 {'original_word': 'test3', 'corrected_word': ('test3', 33, 3)}
]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVHLasMwELzrK/YmKZhCrFsgp36GMcWVlVZU1prVhmBKvt2V4jSUNPhWqpOY8TzkGSd@x2jm@UA4gMUQnGWPMYEfRiSGZzxGdiTEMAWfGPbQiE@J5N987MLLCamXO5DsEm9lBdIiUbZw/TelFq7OpNHn6k/E9Yq4LmS9IjYr4sIZ859i0QphmfJ/vy6hlPLshubOsq1gs@B3hq2GAxIUDnyEZUathRjJR1bZO9/JpWMo46a8uetVI@B2fpfH08PeG5txW1rq8yVTlQ8zqq9wyc95T6VLUvpHRm7/4aZ96IbXvrt03cHj1zTb9tZ9aa3n@Qs)

Answer (score 1):

1. convert to tuples before counter
2. convert back to dicts and add the count
3. sort based on number

```py
def dict_and_add_count(item):
    original_data, count = item
    original_dict = dict(original_data)
    original_dict['corrected_word'] = (*original_dict['corrected_word'], count)
    return original_dict

counted_unique_tuples = Counter(tuple(d.items()) for d in mylist)
dict_with_count = map(dict_and_add_count, counted_unique_tuples.items())
sorted_dicts = sorted(dict_with_count, key=lambda x: x['corrected_word'][1])
```

sorted_dicts will be

```
[{'original_word': 'test2', 'corrected_word': ('test22', 2, 1)},
{'original_word': 'test1', 'corrected_word': ('test12', 3, 2)},
{'original_word': 'test3', 'corrected_word': ('test3', 33, 3)}]
```

Comment: This does not include the counter in the result.

Comment: This is not correct. The Counter is the "count" of equal entries. It is not a serial number.

Comment: and fixed again

Comment: Correct. appreciate your help!